# Flex check whether a datagrid cell is empty

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, cell

I want to check whether a datagrid cell is empty. Although I think the question is simple, I still cannot find a answer.

I have tried to use
(!datagrid.selectedItem.userID)
and
datagrid.selectedItem.userID == ""

All not effect, anybody has the experience?

**UPDATE**: I am so sorry since I input an invalid field name in the datagrid ( but never error hint). Currently I use

(datagrid.selectedItem.userID) to indicate the cell has value, else to indicate the cell is blank.

it works. In case it may misleading others, just clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

For a particular element:

```
if (datagrid.selectedItem.userID != null){

}
```

or to check if a row is selected, you can use:

```
if (datagrid.selectedItem != null){

}
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for the reply, but it still not work.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I tried to use the cell length to indicate whether the cell is blank, it works.